# How do I tell readthedocs which requirements file to load ?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

My readthedocs.org build just started failing ... I am not sure why exactly and not particularly adept at Sphynx.  I don't understand why it's attempting to build things for requirements files outside of the `docs` directory or why it can't find this version of Django suddenly (or why it even needs to).

#### failing message

```
Collecting Django==2.0.3 (from -r /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/django-hitcount/checkouts/latest/example_project/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.3 (from -r /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/django-hitcount/checkouts/latest/example_project/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.1.3, ...1.11.11)
No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.3 (from -r /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/django-hitcount/checkouts/latest/example_project/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

#### repo

This is for: https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount

If you would like to see the ways I have messed this up!  Thanks

Comment: You can specify the `requirements.txt` file in a `.readthedocs.yml` file with this option: `requirements_file: path/to/requirements.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [log file](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-hitcount/builds/6880992/), RTD is parsing your [requirements.txt](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount/blob/master/requirements.txt) at the root of your project, which in turn calls three other `requirements.txt` files and fails at the one in `latest/example_project/requirements.txt` (which is configured to your `master` branch).  You can configure which `requirements.txt` file that RTD should use in your project's [admin](https://readthedocs.org/dashboard/django-hitcount/advanced/).

Give that a try first, and report back.

Else you might have a dependency version conflict amongts your `requirements.txt` files.

Comment: I even looked through the settings but I obviously looked too quickly.  Thank you!  That worked and it's building successfully now.

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify the `requirements.txt` file in a `.readthedocs.yml` file with this line: `requirements_file: path/to/requirements.txt`